# draw(reload) image with cors = "anonimous" on canvas (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, cors

I tryed to reload image to draw it canvas(couse of cors)

this is part of code:

```
    var divicons = $(".leaflet-marker-icon");
    var dx = [];
    var dy = [];
    var mx = [];
    var my = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < divicons.length; k++) {
        var curTransform = divicons[k].style.transform;
        var splitTransform = curTransform.split(",");
        var marginX = parseInt(divicons[k].style.marginTop.replace("px", ""))
        var marginY = parseInt(divicons[k].style.marginLeft.replace("px", ""))
        dx.push(parseFloat(splitTransform[0].split("(")[1].replace("px", "")));
        dy.push(parseFloat(splitTransform[1].replace("px", "")));
        divicons[k].style.transform = "";
        divicons[k].style.left = dx[k] + "px";
        divicons[k].style.top = dy[k] + "px";

        varIconSizeWidth = parseInt(divicons[k].style.width.replace("px", ""))
        varIconSizeHeight = parseInt(divicons[k].style.height.replace("px", ""))
        var img = new Image();
        img.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
        img.src = divicons[k].src + '?d=' + Date.now();
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, dx[k] + mapX + marginY, dy[k] + mapY + marginX);
            console.log(img)
        };
    }

    $(canvas).insertBefore(svgE);
    var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = "test.jpeg";
    link.href = myImage;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    $(link).css("display", "none");
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```

How to reload corrertly, because image did not drew...

also, when I consoled img and divicons[k] - there are some difference(img haven't any style, even img.style = divicons[k].style)....
Also, I'd like to use event, that will start download canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Property names are case-sensitive and in so-called [camel-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (with none-capitalized first letter) so the correct way is with capital **`O`**:

```
img.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");
```

However, CORS is not a requirement to *draw* to canvas, it only applies when you try to extract pixels from it (`toDataURL()`, `toBlob()`, `getImageData()`, `createImageBitmap()`).

Another problem with the code is that the `onload` callback is referencing the `img` variable. However this variable is overridden in parent scope so when `onload` is called it contains a different value, i.e. another image that is likely *not* loaded yet since it will hold the last image source set due to the `onload` not being called until the loop finishes.

To fix, reference `this` instead inside the handler which contains the calling context (image in this case):

```
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(this, dx[k] + mapX + marginY, dy[k] + mapY + marginX);
};
```

And the same goes with the variable `k`; `mapX` and `marginY` do not seem to be defined etc. and will cause you other problems, but out of scope for this question.

Comment: "To fix, reference this instead inside the handler which contains the calling context (image in this case):" THANK YOU!!!!this is what I looking for!! =)

Comment: @Triple-B changing the image onload function to referance this will fix the problem, but the general rule is... "Never create a function inside a conditional block" (for, while, do while, case, if, if else). Function should be declared once and are generally placed at the top (hosted) of the scope block they are part of.